# Find the code from the image

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Find the numerical code from the images.

[image]

You don't get any hints.

Comment: Do you mean find what the code is or find the coded message?

Comment: find what the code is. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 8):

I'm a bit confused what you're asking here

> The middle tile is the multiple of all the other tiles divided by the digit which there is 3 of.

Answer (score 6):

### Code pattern

To get the number in the middle,

1. > multiply all the four numbers orthogonally next to it, then
2. > multiply by all the numbers diagonally on the corners, *except one* which corresponds to the background colour (cyan, magenta, yellow, or black, in the [CMYK colour system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model)).

### How it works

First one:

> **Yellow** is bottom left in the CMYK system, so ignore the bottom left number $4$ but multiply by all the others. Orthogonally, $4\times5\times2\times7=280$. Diagonally, $2\times7\times4=56$. Product is $280\times56=15680$.

Second one:

> **Magenta** is top right in the CMYK system, but apparently we should actually ignore one of the $2$s, not the top right number $6$, and multiply by all the others. Orthogonally, $1\times3\times2\times5=30$. Diagonally, $2\times6\times3=36$. Product is $30\times36=1080$.

Third one:

> **Black** is bottom right in the CMYK system, so ignore the bottom right number $3$ but multiply by all the others. Orthogonally, $3\times1\times2\times4=24$. Diagonally, $1\times8\times3=24$. Product is $24\times24=576$.

Fourth one:

> **Cyan** is top left in the CMYK system, so ignore the top left number $1$ but multiply by all the others. Orthogonally, $9\times4\times4\times1=144$. Diagonally, $1\times2\times3=6$. Product is $144\times6=864$.